# The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE in c# dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using entity framework and created DBcontext from package manager.. Everything working fine in localhost, when i tried to publish and access the url through postman the above issue happening, I tried lots of options

1. NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the user in sql server
2. installed core installation support.

some body please help. Below is the response which i am getting from the postman
{
"status": "failure",
"message": "Cannot open database "BigDay" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.",
"data": null
}

Comment: Can you share the connection used by your application with sensitive information masked?

Comment: autogenerated in Dbcontect class optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=True;");

Comment: It seems that the user / login which is executing the task has no access to the Database BigDay...

Comment: I dont know what should i do to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to define a username and password for the database to which the program is connected and login with it, and the second way, will reduce security a bit.

I will explain both way below

> first way:

1. open your sql server management
2. go security folder
3. go login folders
4. right click login and click New Login
5. enter loginname and password
6. User Mapping Tab select your database and bottom panel in role membership check db_datareader and check db_datawriter.

Then enter this information in the program and connect with this username and password.

> second way:

1. open your sql server management
2. go security folder
3. go login folders
4. right click NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select properties
5. in opened dialog select Server Roles
6. Check sysadmin or server admin and then OK.

[image]

Comment: Sounds a little bit dangerous. Principle of least privilege: give NETWORK SERVICE just read/write access to the databse it needs

Comment: Yes, it is better to login with a username and password so that this permission is not required

Comment: Well no, it's better to give IIS a specific Windows service account to run from, then give only that account the exact SQL permissions it needs. SQL Authentication (as opposed to Windows Auth) should be avoided where possible

Comment: @Charlieface I do not think there is a need for all this complexity

Comment: I suppose it depends what else is running under NETWORK SERVICE and whether you trust it. If yes, then certainly, at the least I would **not** give it sysadmin access. CONNECT SQL on the server and db_datareader/writer on the database is enough

Comment: The program is guaranteed if it has read and write access with a username and password.

Comment: What is guaranteed? Are you saying it must have sysadmin? Sorry I don't quite understand, maybe got a language misunderstanding here.

Comment: In the second case, yes, you are right, your security will decrease. But in the first case, security is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties

2.In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

Most cases, this should fix the problem